# gyroscope's motion

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> A certain gyroscope is a sphere of radius $10$cm, spinning clockwise (when viewed
>   from above) on its vertical axis at a rate of $3$ revolutions per second. We throw it
>   horizontally at a speed of $2$m/sec, in the direction of the positive $y$-axis, releasing
>   it at time $t = 0$. When released, the centre is located $20$m above the origin,
>   along the z-axis. It accelerates downwards at $9.8m$/$sec^2$. Consider
>   the motion of the point on the gyroscope that (at the time of release) sits at the
>   intersection of the equator and the first quadrant of the $xz$-plane. Describe this
>   motion as a parametrized curve $(x, y, z) = f(t)$. Then find its position and its
>   velocity vector, $2$ seconds after release.

Any help would be nice. I have no idea how to really start. Thanks for any guidance.

I think that since I am given information about velocity and acceleration, I can use that info for the first and second derivative of position vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I would do is convert all the data to uniform units so I can
just use numbers for time and position. Meters and seconds look like
good units. So the radius is $0.1$, the initial horizontal speed is $2$,
the initial height of the center of the sphere above the origin is $20$,
and the downward acceleration is $9.8$.

We now have information about first and second derivatives of position vectors,
but we do not have explicit information about the first and second
derivatives of the vector $f(t)$.

What we are told explicitly in the problem statement are some facts about the position of the center of the sphere at time $t$, let me call it $p(t)$, and the 
position of the chosen point on the equator of the sphere relative to the center of the sphere.
Let me use $r(t)$ to name the vector that takes us from the center of the sphere to the chosen point on the equator at time $t$.

Then $f(t) = p(t) + r(t)$.

To work out $r(t)$, we need $r(0)$.
You may be able to see that directly or you may need to find the exact point
$f(0)$ that is described as "the intersection of the equator and the first quadrant of the $xz$-plane" and the position of the center $p(0)$ at
that same instant, and solve the equation above for $r(0)$.

The motion of the point on the equator *relative to the center of the sphere* is simply the motion due to the rotation of the sphere.
If the center of the sphere were sitting motionless at the origin,
the rotation of the sphere would take the point on the equator on a circular path of radius $10$ around the origin.
You can work out a formula for that circular path, parameterized by time $t$.
Two hints: (1) since the sphere's axis is vertical (parallel to the $z$-axis),
a point on the equator is always at the same height ($z$-coordinate)
as the origin, so the $z$-coordinate of $r(t)$ must be zero;
and (2) since the sphere rotates $3$ times per second, 
if the center of the sphere did not move then the point on the equator would return to its starting position after $\frac13$ second, 
so the function for $r(t)$ must ensure that $r\left(\frac13\right) = r(0)$,
and $t=\frac13$ should be the first time after $t=0$ when $r(t) = r(0)$.

You can also work out the formula for $p(t)$, the motion of the 
center of the sphere, starting with the given starting position of
the center of the sphere, $p(0)$, and applying the given initial velocity
and the given acceleration, both expressed as vectors.

Once you have fully worked out $p(t)$ and $r(t)$ each by themselves,
then you can add them together.

And then you can also answer the part asking for data "$2$ seconds after release."